# Does the multivariable limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

[image: The limit]

I tried approach by line, parabola, polar coordinates, double limit. I do not know any other way to determine whether this limit exists or not.

Comment: You should add some details about the paths you tried.

Comment: Can you specifiy the restrictions regarding $x$ and $y$? E.g. $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$...

Comment: i tried y=ax, y=ax^2+bx. then polar coords x=Q*cos(P), y=Q*sin(P). And I do not have any other information about this limit.

Comment: Note: According to Taylor, for some $f:[-1,\infty[\to\mathbb R$ that is in $o(t)$ as $t\to0$, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{1+xy}-1}{x+y}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy+f(xy)}{x+y}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x+y}\left(1+\frac{f(xy)}{xy}\right)$$ and the last limit is not well-defined because of $\frac{xy}{x+y}$.

Comment: Yes it does. I misscalculated the approach by parabola. That was it, thank you for your time.